# retrieving information from curl

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am retrieving information from soundcloud using curl. it gives lot of information. but I want to filter it.

```
<?php
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks ');
    curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
?>
```

how can I filter information coming from it like `stream-url`, `downloadable`, `title` etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of tools for extracting what you want.

The stream you're downloading is an xml file, so you can pipe the output of that to some parser, either in php or directly on the commandline.

You can see the builtin XML parser for php here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

**EDIT** Here's an example usage

```
<?php
// Download the Data
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks ');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$xml_data = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

//Parse it
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_data);

foreach ($xml->track as $track) {
    print "{$track->title}\n";
    print "\tStream URL: {$track->{'stream-url'}}\n";
}

?>
```

I ended up using SimpleXML instead

Comment: thanks  it will be very help fule for me up to integrating api

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$url = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $body, $data);
xml_parser_free($parser);

print "<h1>The XML as a relatively flat PHP data structure</h1>";
print "<pre>";
print htmlentities($body);
print "</pre>";
print "<hr />";
print "<h1>The Raw XML Data</h1>";
print "<pre>";
print htmlentities(print_r($data, true));
print "</pre>";
print "<pre>";

?>
```

Comment: thanks  it will be very help fule for me up to integrating api